# Update variable instantly in React

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am making a memory game in React and I need to update a variable instantly because users interact with the images pretty quick. How can I force a state update? I cannot wait for React to decide when to update a variable, I need an instant way to update it. Is that possible?

```
<div className="page" style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + "/images/BG1.jpg" + ")", }}>


                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "20%", top: "10%", }} src={card1} onClick={() => chooseCard(1)} />
                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "20%", top: "30%", }} src={card2} onClick={() => chooseCard(2)} />
                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "20%", top: "50%", }} src={card3} onClick={() => chooseCard(3)} />

                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "60%", top: "10%", }} src={card4} onClick={() => chooseCard(4)} />
                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "60%", top: "30%", }} src={card5} onClick={() => chooseCard(5)} />
                <img className="cardStyle" style={{ left: "60%", top: "50%", }} src={card6} onClick={() => chooseCard(6)} />


            </div>
```

So I call the function chooseCard(cardNumber) to know which card was cliked.

In chooseCard(cardNumber) I check if its open or closed.

```
if (card[cardNumber] != 0) {
            card[cardChosen] = 0;
            UpdateCard(card);
        }
        else {
            card[cardChosen] = 1;
            UpdateCard(card);
        }
```

The problem is that its not updating instantly. So sometimes when the user clicks its still using the old state of card and it doesnt recognize it being open or closed.

Comment: `I need to update a variable instantly` Are you talking about changing state? The re-render happens pretty much immediately, but closure variables will never change (they're a local snapshot of the state, not the state itself). I think you'll need to give us an example of code that isn't doing what you want.

Comment: So from what I see the only way to update a variable is using const [card1, UpdateCard1]. So when I do UpdateCard and set it to Open for example. Sometimes is not instant since the state hasn`t changed yet and when the users clicks it, the program still thinks the Card is Closed. Is there a way to update a variable instantly so I dont wait for the state to change?

Comment: `Sometimes is not instant since the state hasn't changed yet and when the users clicks it` *What's* not instant? If you're talking about the local const `card1`, that will never change. It's a `const` after all. If you're talking about when react re-renders, it's pretty close to instant (the user won't be able to notice a delay, except in extreme circumstances). Again, please show us the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: Say for example I have const [card1, UpdateCard1] = useState(0) and I use UpdateCard1(1) to set card1 to 1. Its not instant. It takes a couple of seconds. Is there a quicker way to update a variable? I dont need to use the const. Is there a quicker way to have a variable start with 0 and be able to update to 1? If I use the Javascript way to var card1 = 0; It doesnt seem to update

Comment: I think you are experiencing this common pitfall: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value . See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately If you'd like more information, please edit your question with the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: Ok, I updated question, does it help? It definetely is waht you stated.

Comment: Thanks, the code example does help. The problem is **not** what i guessed it was. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (card[cardNumber] != 0) {
  card[cardChosen] = 0;
  UpdateCard(card);
} else {
  card[cardChosen] = 1;
  UpdateCard(card);
}
```

The problem you're running into is that you're mutating the old state, not creating a new one. When you call `UpdateCard`, react will do an `===` comparison between the old card and the new card. Since it's the same object, it looks like nothing has changed and react skips the render.

Instead, you must copy the state and modify the copy, such as:

```
if (card[cardNumber] != 0) {
  const newCard = [...card] // create a shallow copy
  newCard[cardChosen] = 0;
  UpdateCard(newCard);
} else {
  const newCard = [...card] // create a shallow copy
  newCard[cardChosen] = 1;
  UpdateCard(newCard);
}
```

For more information, see this documentation: https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#treat-state-as-read-only